# ASP.NET Core : how to create PDF Product Catalog With a template with an image in the background

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, e-commerce, pdfsharp, product-catalog

I am developing a web application with ASP.NET Core. The application will select the products on the e-commerce website, create headings according to categories and subcategories, and create a PDF catalog with product information images properly underneath (I hope).

But I haven't been very successful with PdfSharp right now, everything works with coordinates and it is very difficult to design something original. Two solutions came to my mind:

1. Upload a PDF template and edit it with PDFSharp or a similar plug-in. Here, perhaps we can place a fixed photo area and text area with a form and enter product information there. Here we can name the text and photo fields, such as texbox1 picture1.
2. Prepare a table on the PdfSharp side, use it just like a template and have the products listed.

I haven't quite decided what to do right now. I added an area to upload font files and templates to the plugin I developed, and I also made the information that should be included in the catalog, such as picture, sku, title, selectable with a checkbox. I don't know how to continue. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

There are no tables in PDFsharp.

Consider using MigraDoc which comes with PDFsharp and supports tables and other document features.

Comment: I found it some library name of QuestPDF. I can try it this maybe